# MVC View Condiciones

Tags: c#, .net, mvc

Necesito que mi programa haga el siguiente control de flujo, pero el else no lo detecta, es como si no estuviera escrito.

Código:

```
 <table class="table">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Remitente</th>
                       <th>Asunto</th>
                       <th>Recibido</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>

                   @foreach (var correo in Model)
                   {
                       DateTime horaRecibida = @correo.recibido;
                       DateTime horaActual = DateTime.Now;

                       Double minutos = horaRecibida.Subtract(horaActual).TotalMinutes;

                       if (minutos > 3)
                       {
                 <tr style="background-color:red">
                       <td>@correo.remitente</td>
                       <td>@correo.asunto</td>
                       <td>@correo.recibido</td>
                   </tr>
                        }

                      else
                       {
                        <tr>
                      <td>@correo.remitente</td>
                      <td>@correo.asunto</td>
                      <td>@correo.recibido</td>
                        </tr>
                       }
                   }       

               </tbody>
           </table>
```

Error:

> Mensaje de error del compilador: CS1513: } expected

Este error salta en una clase auto generada, si elimino el control de flujo de mi clase .cshtml no hay ningún problema.

Comment: Tendrás que explicarte mejor ¿a qué te refieres con que no detecta nada más? Además en tu código estás restando al `DateTime` `horaRecibida` su propio valor, supongo que será un error de transcripción.

Comment: Me refiero que a la hora de lanzar la aplicación sale un error en la visualización,ya que el else no lo detecta, es como si no estuviera escrito.

Comment: Tras el `else` te sobran también los paréntesis

Comment: Hector, acabas de editar la pregunta para quitar esos parentesis y lo que te comenta @AsierVillanueva en su primer comentario... eso significa que tras arreglar eso, sigues teniendo el mismo problema?

Comment: Si, sigo con el mismo problema, he estado mirando varias webs y algunos ejemplos añaden @: delante de alguna etiqueta, probé con casi todas, pero no consigo solucionarlo.

Comment: Tienes errores de consola o has depurado para ver qué pasa? Nosotros no podemos depurar por ti. Por favor mira [ask] para añadir toda la informacion relevante para su resolución. Un saludo

Comment: No existe ningún error de consola, únicamente de visualización en la view, a causa de que no sabe como interpretar mi control de flujo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me ha costado pero he conseguido reproducir el problema.

Parece un problema del motor Razor porque sí que hay un error pero resulta extraño el código que genera en la clase autogenerada: quita el `}` final del `foreach`.

En realidad el problema está en la instrucción:

```
DateTime horaRecibida = @correo.recibido;
```

En la que te sobra la `@`

Comment: Tenia 15 minutos buscando el error y no lograba reproducirlo. No me habia fijado en el @ restante.

Answer (score 1):

Este es el código corregido:
Te he agregado Math.Abs al obtener los minutos, el problema principal era que cerrabas el for each antes de tiempo y el @ sobrante en correo.recibido.

```
                       @foreach (var correo in Model)
                       {

                           DateTime horaRecibida = correo.recibido;
                           DateTime horaActal = DateTime.Now;

                           Double minutos = Math.Abs(horaRecibida.Subtract(horaActal).TotalMinutes);


                           if (minutos > 10)
                           {
                   <tr style="background-color:red">
                       <td>@correo.remitente</td>1
                       <td>@correo.asunto</td>
                       <td>@correo.recibido</td>
                   </tr>

                           }
                           if (minutos < 10)
                           {
                   <tr>
                       <td>@correo.remitente</td>
                       <td>@correo.asunto</td>
                       <td>@correo.recibido</td>
                   </tr>
                           }
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Diría que te sobran los paréntesis del *else*:

```
 if(condition)
 {
      ...
 }
 else
 {
      ...
 }
```

Comment: Hola Miguialberto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Este error es un *error tipografico*. En vez de contestar, para este tipo de errores has de pulsar bajo la pregunta en Reportar/Cerrar y poner *No relacionado > Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.* Un saludo.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, el problema no esta en los parentesis, sigue pasando lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que únicamente tendrías que usar una @ en esa sentencia if. Tu código quedaría como sigue:

```
@foreach (var correo in Model)
{
       DateTime horaRecibida = @correo.recibido;
       DateTime horaActal = DateTime.Now;

       Double minutos = horaRecibida.Subtract(horaRecibida).TotalMinutes;

       @if (minutos > 3)
       {
           <tr style="background-color:red">
           <td>@correo.remitente</td>
           <td>@correo.asunto</td>
           <td>@correo.recibido</td>
           </tr>
       }
       else
       { 
           <tr>
           <td>@correo.remitente</td>
           <td>@correo.asunto</td>
           <td>@correo.recibido</td>
           </tr>
       }
}
```

Comment: Si pongo el @ delante de ese if, solo arrastro mas errores.

Comment: Hola Irene. Los terminos como *"creo"* son de duda. No queda una respuesta muy creible si la usas. Has de estar más segura :P  Un saludo